# ios settings bundle manipulation from inside app

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

If a user toggles a setting to "ON" in the settings for my app (from my settings.bundle), can I have the app toggle it back to "OFF" on the next time the app is brought to the foreground / launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Just use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: NO forKey:<your-key>]
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: It is a good idea to make sure the setting is actually saved to the system by calling [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  synchronize];

Comment: If you write apps that crash, then yes ;)

Comment: according to the apple doc: "...use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit)..." I understand this as no guarantee that settings will be persistent if app is closed just after settings are set. I might be wrong:-)

Comment: Hah, great comments. I would rather error or the side of `synchronize` -ing too early in this case because you never know when there will be a system level crash, phone in water, dead battery, etc. I just assume the elements are against me!